# PHP simple JSON-RPC

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to create JSON-RPC HTTP service. I am using POST method.

**rest.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($input);

$output = $json->num + 10;
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

**Input:**

```
{"num": 10 }
```

**Output:**

```
20
```

Now I am trying to implement more methods, so then I can use input like this:

```
{ 
    "method":"add", 
    "params": {
        "num1": 15, 
        "num2": 10
    }
}
```

So I add function to **rest.php**:

```
public function add($n1, $n2) {
    return $n1 + $n2;
}
```

Q: How to determine called method and execute it in **rest.php** with new input?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($input);

foreach ($json->params as $param) {
    $params[] = $param;
}

$output = call_user_func_array($json->method, $params);
echo json_encode($output);

function add($n1, $n2) {
    return $n1 + $n2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [method_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) and [function_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.function-exists.php) (depending of your needs) to check if the string you get matches an existing element.

Then, you can use [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func.php) or [call_user_method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-method.php) to execute the function.

For example :

```
<?php
class foo{
    public function add($n1, $n2) {
        return $n1 + $n2;
    } 
}

$method = "add";
$object = new foo();
$n1 = 1;
$n2 = 8;
if(method_exists($object, $method))
{
    call_user_method($method, $object, $n1, $n2);
}
```

EDIT : In this example, I assigned n1 and n2 parameters hard coded values. In your case, you can get the params array you get from the JSON and give it as parameter to all your methods. In this way, you don't have to test received parameters outside the method body.

Comment: added my test to original post